# Is it legal to trade 1 wood for 1 wood + 1 hay?

Tags: catan

I ran into this situation. I had helped out a player by not placing the robber on them with my knight card. To sweeten the deal, she agreed to give me 1 wood + 1 hay in exchange for 1 wood. Is this legal?

The board mentions that trading 1 wood for 2 wood is illegal, but is 1 wood + 1 hay considered legal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would argue the rules say this is not legal.  Quoting from rules found on [Catan Website](https://www.catan.com/service/game-rules)

> However, you cannot give away cards, or trade matching resources (“trade” 3 ore for 1 ore, for example).

Your example in effect breaks both those rules.  You are trading wood for wood which is illegal.  The exact amounts don't matter, the example is 3 and 1 ore but if there is a matching resource in both sets then it is not a trade.

If you take out wood cards from your trade then you are in effect giving away a Wheat card for free which is also against the rules.

Comment: Sure, but you can still end up at the same result. "You may trade as many times as you want, using single or multiple cards". Trade one wood for two hay. Afterwards, trade one hay for the wood. The rules aren't as iron-clad as one would hope.

Comment: @Polygnome But then you'd have to have two hay

Comment: @Kevin or brick, sheep or ore. Any 3rd card that isn't wood.

Comment: The rules mights not be as Ironclad as one would hope I agree.  Then I think Its down to players to do things in spirit of the rules and not make a series of elaborate trades in order to manipulate them.  But I guess that ultimately that's down to taste of each group and what's fun for them.